# reformatting people-planning table in powerquery

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a table:

| Date | personA | personB | personC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/24 | x |  | H |
| 2/1/24 |  | x | Y |
| 3/1/24 | A |  | x |
| 4/1/24 | Y | x |  |
| 5/1/24 | x | x |  |

Above the table I have a table with a title "Person" and 1 cell with a dropdown allowing for a selection of PersonA-PersonB-PersonC.

I'd like to create a new table contaning all dates for a specific person where the value is X or Y (ignoring other values).
so the output is row per letter with all corresponding dates.

| person | letter | date | date | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| personA | X | 1/1/2024 | 5/1/2024 | ... |
| personA | Y | 4/1/2024 |  |  |

I already created a datasource for the person with a list of the persons.
I don't find how to filter column "table_person" with values.
The steps after that are equally outside of my knowledge. I would look to remove the 'unneedded' collumns, distinct the X and Y, unpivot the table and transpose it in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Get Data" from your table, sort by date (just in case your data is not already sorted in the table), set the data type of the date column to Text, then on that column use Extract > Text before delimiter and choose "Space" to throw away the time component.

Right click the date column and choose "Unpivot other columns". This will output three columns, one for dates, one for person (column called "Attribute" by default but you can change this in the formula bar), third column called "Value" has your X and Y and Z - again you can rename this.

Filter the person column for the person you have brought in as a parameter. Filter values for X or Y (watch out for case sensitivity if there could be x and X).

Now for the trick - do a Group By on Person and Letter, and choose an arbitrary aggregation such as Sum for the Date column (call the new column something like "Dates"). This won't work, but you will then fix it. In the formula bar, replace the List.Sum with Text.Combine and add a separator such as semicolon:

```
= Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Person", "Letter"}, {{"Dates", each List.Sum([Date]), type text}})
```

becomes

```
= Table.Group(#"Grouped Rows1", {"Person", "Letter"}, {{"Dates", each Text.Combine([Date],";"), type nullable date}})
```

All that is left is to split the new column by delimiter at the semicolon.
In my code I did not filter by person, I just kept all of the results and applied a sensible sort order at the end.

My code for the whole thing, assuming your data starts in a Table called Table1 (simply adjust as needed):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Sorted Rows by date" = Table.Sort(Source,{{"Date", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Changed Type Date to Text" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows by date",{{"Date", type text}, {"personA", type text}, {"personB", type text}, {"personC", type text}}),
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type Date to Text", {{"Date", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, " "), type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter", {"Date"}, "Person", "Letter"),
    #"Uppercased Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Letter", Text.Upper, type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Uppercased Text", each ([Letter] = "X" or [Letter] = "Y")),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Person", "Letter"}, {{"Dates", each Text.Combine([Date],";"), type nullable date}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Grouped Rows", {{"Dates", type text}}, "en-GB"), "Dates", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Dates.1", "Dates.2", "Dates.3"}),
    #"Sorted Rows by Person and Letter" = Table.Sort(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Person", Order.Ascending}, {"Letter", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Changed Type back to Date" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows by Person and Letter",{{"Dates.1", type date}, {"Dates.2", type date}, {"Dates.3", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type back to Date"
```

Comment: I can't upvote you for lack of reputation, otherwise I would upvote twice ;). 
This was an amazing good answer. I learned lots creating it.